# Automotive questions appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm an active member of stackoverflow.com and I was looking to see if the stackexchange suite of sites had an automotive one. This was the closest I could find. Is it appropriate to ask automotive questions on this site? It's not really a electronic automotive question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not, if it is not related to electronics or robotics it does not fit here.

[Area51 had a site proposed for automotive](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1321/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll search more closely. I googled "automotive stackexchange" and this was the closest match. Thanks!

Comment: @kralco626, got you a link.

Comment: thanks! hopefully it will get into beta :) until then i guess i'll look elsewhere for answers :)

Comment: @kralco626, commit and help it along. Get others to commit, then it really gets steam.

Comment: way ahead of you :) I already did. I would deff use a site like that! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Are you designing/debugging automotive electronics on a component/software level?  **Yes.**

Your stereo stopped working?  **No.**

Answer (score 2):

There was a site called "Automotive Electronics Development" a couple months ago.  However, it was closed down in Pruning Season as being too niche in comparison to E&R.

I know this because I was a follower (one of ~30).  Now, it's only existence is a few comments in the Google cache that can be found by searching for *"Automotive Electronics Development" site:area51.stackexchange.com*.

Ask your Automotive Electronics Development questions here!

If your source for automotive electronics is the Advance Auto down the road, however, you're probably better off asking a mechanic for now and following the [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1321/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair) proposal for later.